# the meaning of the phrase 'pricked off on a list'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ...  among them he moves softly, plain Thomas Cromwell, a greeting
>   here and a word there, spreading reassurance: the Crown’s case is in
>   order, no upsets are expected or will be tolerated, we shall all be
>   home for supper and sleep safely in our own beds tonight. Lord Sandys,
>   Lord Audley, Lord Clinton and many lords more, **each pricked off on a
>   list** as they take their seats:
>
> *-Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

Does this mean their names are marked on an attendance list by someone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it means to make a small puncture in the parchment with a [pricker](http://www.winchestermuseumcollections.org.uk/index.asp?page=item&mwsquery=%7Bcollection%7D=%7Barchaeology%7DAND%7BIdentity%20number%7D=%7BWINCM:VR72%20S3063%7D), rather than mark it using ink (a quill, inkwell and blotter might have been awkward and/or messy to use).  See definition 2 of "prick" in the [*The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Current English* (1919)](https://books.google.com/books?id=niMFAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA653&lpg=PA653&dq=prick+%22mark+off%22&source=bl&ots=yq0lHMr5Pa&sig=urRDvex_KtD_BvgBYLKFbucyi3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwi4kOukr9bIAhVB6mMKHWHFBhs#v=onepage&q=prick%20%22mark%20off%22&f=false): "mark off (name &c. list) with a prick, select (sheriff) thus."

See also page 39 of [Shakespeare Quarterly (1956)](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnkUAAAAIAAJ&q=%22prick+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjVmebBvdbIAhVDlIgKHRdBDlM), "...'prick off': 'to tick off on a list' (NED 15)," in which "NED" stood for *[New English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_English_Dictionary)* (the original title of the *Oxford English Dictionary*).

Apparently, it was also commonly used in surveying to create copies of the plans by laying the original map or plan over a blank paper then making small holes at key locations which could then be drawn by connecting the dots ([A Complete Treatise on Practical Land Surveying](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oe5hAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA121-IA2&lpg=PA121-IA2&dq=%22to+prick+off%22&source=bl&ots=6qNOv216T3&sig=jJmXsgyglIjaCaJVZMnwgB9oscE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwB2oVChMIj7uRqKzWyAIVS_FjCh06jgII#v=onepage&q=%22to%20prick%20off%22&f=false)).

The usage is archaic since we have more portable writing instruments now but [not that uncommon](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22prick+off%22+list) for the time period the book is set in.  It's used in a variety of topics:

*[The Statutes at Large of South Carolina: Acts, 1716-1752](https://books.google.com/books?id=oek4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA682&lpg=PA682&dq=%22prick+off%22&source=bl&ots=EdYFYez4XH&sig=t_bX9L1aufNDKgurZazv3f3SpGY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMItrfa9q7WyAIVTf5jCh0HuANB#v=onepage&q=prick%20off&f=false)*
*[Design and Construction in Wood](http://chestofbooks.com/home-improvement/woodworking/Design-Construction-Wood/Picture-Frame-Clamp-Continued.html)*
*[Mathematical Instruments](https://books.google.com/books?id=wwPwNnJGcKoC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22prick+off%22&source=bl&ots=V0nU8F59BN&sig=ftl7XEV9wiRY2Xn6TMWIU2B_8Ws&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAzgKahUKEwjb0pOEqNbIAhVEfYgKHVMwD_k#v=onepage&q=%22prick%20off%22&f=false)*
*[The Young Surveyor's Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=IeA2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=%22prick+off%22&source=bl&ots=A1cQQXnfm1&sig=gNVdpliIKRRQG8kuOOEbuuajPgM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBWoVChMItqfp4KfWyAIViZeICh0G7gQW#v=onepage&q=%22prick%20off%22&f=false)*

Note:
What I found much harder to find was the strange use of *sheriff* in the definition above.  It seems to have been an obsolete form of *[shrieve](http://www.finedictionary.com/Shrieve.html)*, which is an obsolete form of *[shrive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shrive)*.  According to the [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shrive&allowed_in_frame=0), *shrive* comes from the Old English *scrifan*, which among other uses was "apparently originally 'to write'."